# Build Kernel Module CentOS6

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, vpn, kernel-module, centos6

Im trying to build [Klips capable version of OpenSwan](https://github.com/xelerance/Openswan/blob/master/README) using this [guide](http://www.gettechgo.com/l2tp-vpn-setup-on-cent-o-s-6/), where it goes something like

```
make KERNELSRC=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build module
```

it gives the fol output

```
KLIPS26 module built successfully. 
ipsec.ko is in /home/naruto/Downloads/Openswan-master/modobj26

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11662573 Feb 20 10:32 ipsec.ko
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 367195   15808    8244  391247   5f84f ipsec.ko

use make minstall as root to install it
```

but when i run

```
make KERNELSRC=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build install minstall
```

it gives me

```
 make[3]:/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/Documentation/DocBook/Makefile:No such file or directory
 make[3]: *** No rule to make target/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/Documentation/DocBook/Makefile'Stop.
make[2]: *** [help] Error 2
```

i do have a dir `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64`
 but `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64/Documentation/DocBook` does not exist

How can i build `ipsec.ko` into the kernel, plz guide

Regards

Comment: Have you tried `modules_install` target instead of `minstall`? And why do you have two targets instead of one?

Comment: no i'll try `modules_install` now, and by two targets u mean? im bit new to this linux kernel building stuff...

Comment: You put `install` and `minstall` at the same time. Those are make targets.

Answer (score 1):

Both kernel looks different to me. one is 2.6.18 other is 2.6.32 and you might also need kernel-devel

Comment: thanks for your time, that was a typo, fixed it, also before the build i installed `yum install kernel-devel`